Can one roll-up summary field update a records before the other updates?
I have two roll-up summary fields that calculate the number of keywords on a project.

The first field is calculating the total number of keywords and
the second calculates the number of specific keywords.

In my trigger I do logic against the total keywords and not against the one with filters. All keywords are sent in as a batch and when they are created the roll-up fields calculate and update the project.
The question I have is, is it possible that the roll-up summary that checks for keywords with filters could be calling my trigger before the other roll-up summary field has a chance to finish calculating?

It depends. Are you strictly using the standard rollup summary system, or are you using a trigger-based rollup system like DLRS?

I am using the standard rollup summary system.
